# How to shared file in Google Drive API v3 in php?

Tags: google-drive-api

How to share file in Google Drive API v3?I have listed of file and I want to add share functionality with Laravel?

Comment: I can not find out any code example?Can you help me for that?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean sharing a file with another user, then you can do the following

```
client = new Google_Client();
// setup the client the way you do
// ....

service = new Google_Service_Drive(client)
$role = 'writer';
$userEmail = 'user@gmail.com';
$fileId = 'The ID of the file to be shared';

$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
  'type' => 'user',
  'role' => $role,
  'emailAddress' => $userEmail
));

$request = $service->permissions->create(
  $fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id')
);
```

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing

Check my git repo for more useful examples
https://github.com/sazaamout/gDrive/blob/master/gDrive.php

Comment: Is there anyway to disable the download via permission?