# How we can change the permissions for editors/writers for not sharing the google docs using google docs API?

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am working on google docs API and google drive API. I am facing one issue while setting the permissions for editors/writers for not able to share the google docs to anyone except for the owner using google docs API.

Can anyone tell me how we can set or change the permissions so that no one can share the google docs to anyone except the owner.I went through this links https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#isShareableByEditors%28%29 and found one function **isShareableByEditors()** and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files in this link I found one more function **writersCanShare()**. But I am not able to understand How I put this function or set the functions to get my work done.

**I want to do it with google API only with PHP language**. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shared file in Google Drive API v3 in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564230/how-to-shared-file-in-google-drive-api-v3-in-php)

Comment: @Emel, I just want that only owner can share the google docs not all the users who are on editor mode.How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to make users not share the Google Document, while the user can edit the Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.

I think that in this case, `writersCanShare` is required to be `false`. I think that your direction is correct. So, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

This script uses Drive API v3.

```php
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your authorization script.
$fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID.

$metadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
  "writersCanShare" => false,
]);
$res = $service->files->update($fileId, $metadata);
```

- If an error related to the scope occurs, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata` and/or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and please authorize the scopes again. But, if you are required to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, I think that you can use it.
- When this script is run, the user who is not the owner of Document cannot share the document while the user can edit the document.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)